# What is the algebraic multiplicity if the eigenvalue is 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The charasteristic polynomial came out to be:

$P(x) = x^3$

I said that the algebraic multiplicity of $x=0$ is $3$.

But i was said by a a friend that its one.

Another case:

$P(x) = x^2(1-x)$.

Can I get some clarifications about this?

Comment: In algebra the multiplicity of the root of $p(x)=x^3$ is indeed three.  And it's $2$ in your second example.  Maybe in the context in which you are encountering it, they have a different definition for that term.  I'm not sure, my linear algebra is rusty.

Comment: You're right: the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is $3$. For $P(x)=x^2(1-x)$, $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ and $1$ has multiplicity $1$. Your firend probably confused with the *geometric* multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, the multiplicity of the root $x=0$ in $P(x)=x^3$ is $3$, and in $P(x)=x^2(1-x)$ the root $x=0$ has multiplicity $2$ and $x=1$ has multiplicity 1.

(Why people give perfectly good answers in comments and leave the question to hang around forever in an 'unanswered' state is beyond me).